# how to identify records where the array elements have same items?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i have a table which has some sample data like

```
id                      rollNo         parent             children(array)   
ABC                     12345          P123                C1
                                                           C2
                                                           C3
    
ABC                     54678          P123                C3
                                                           C1
                                                           C2

DEF                     123245          P1223              C5
                                                           C6
                                                           C7
    
DEF                     546278          P1223              C0
                                                           C11
                                                           C12
```

how can i get the id of such records where they have same parent with same set of children but different rollNo.

i could only group them till id and parent, how can we group them at children level in gcp?

```sql
select id from myTable group by id,parent having count(itemNbr) >1 ;
```

expected output:

```
ABC
```

Comment: question is a bit confusing, if you could add 'expected output record(s)' as another section above, that would clarify exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

> how to identify records where the array elements have same items?

Since an array is an ordered list, you need to sort it first before comparing it with other.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'ABC' id, '12345' rollNo, 'P123' parent, ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'] children UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC', '54678', 'P123', ['C3', 'C1', 'C2'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEF', '123245', 'P1223', ['C5', 'C6', 'C7'] UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEF', '456278', 'P1223', ['C0', 'C11', 'C22']
)
-- query starts here
SELECT id, parent, (SELECT STRING_AGG(c ORDER BY c) FROM t.children c) sorted
  FROM sample_table t
 GROUP BY id, parent, sorted HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;

-- query result
+-----+--------+------------+
| id  | parent |   sorted   |
+-----+--------+------------+
| ABC | P123   |  C1,C2,C3  |
+-----+--------+------------+
```